# How To Make A Lightbox Animation Effect Only Using Javascript (no library)

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox

I am just new to Javascript. I want to implement lightbox effect without using jQuery. I can successfully add a fixed div with 100% height and width of body element by using Javascript but there is no animation effect.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Lightbox Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lightboxstyle.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><img class="preview" src="images/blue.jpg" title="blue"></li>
    <li><img class="preview" src="images/red.jpg" title="red"></li>
    <li><img class="preview" src="images/yellow.jpg" title="yellow"></li>
    <li><img class="preview" src="images/green.jpg" title="green"></li>
  </ul>
  <script src="lightbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Stlesheet**

```
.preview {list-style: none;display:inline;width:200px;}
ul li {display:inline;margin-left:1%}
body {background-color:#eee;}
#lightbox {
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
z-index: 999;
background-image:url(images/1.png);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function lightboxboot(){
var lightbox=document.createElement("div")
lightbox.id="lightbox"
var ul=document.getElementsByTagName("ul")
ul[0].insertBefore(lightbox)
for (var x=1;x<100;x++){
setTimeout(function(){
lightbox.style.width=x+"%";
lightbox.style.height=x+"%";
},50)
}
}
var image=document.getElementsByClassName("preview")
for (var i=0;i<image.length;i++){
image[i].onclick=lightboxboot;
}
```

The lightbox div can still cover the entire body element after the script runs over but these is no animation effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var x=1;x<100;x++){
setTimeout(function(){
lightbox.style.width=x+"%";
lightbox.style.height=x+"%";
},50)
}
```

Is wrong. You set a bunch of timeouts for the same time and try to access x wrongly. Here:

```
for (var x=1;x<100;x++){
    setTimeout(function(x){
        lightbox.style.width=x+"%";
        lightbox.style.height=x+"%";
    },x*50,x)
}
```

Comment: This still won't work. It has fixed the timing issue, but it'll set the `width` and `height` to `100` every time. Each `setTimeout` function needs to preserve a reference to the value of `x` at the time it is made. A closure would work for this.

Comment: Yes, in most cases, passing `x` as an additional argument to `setTimeout` would work, because in modern browsers `setTimeout` will pass the additional parameters as arguments to the internal function. Though OP should be aware that some older versions of browsers (IE especially) may not support this.

Comment: Nobody supports IE, IE supports nobody.

Comment: Thanks It works. But in the official tutorial, the setTimeout method has only two parameters but in this code the setTimeout method has three paras, a function, a "x*50", a "x". Can anyone explain this to newbie? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what tutorial you're talking about, but x is an argument passed to the function - it gives the function the correct x-value.

Comment: I mean I do not know what the last x is for

Comment: It's passing the x in the loop to the x in the function. It's like `(function(x){…})(x)`, except with timeout.